# Symmetric sub-simplicial sets of the nerve of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

The nerve of $\mathbb{N}$ is the simplicial set $N\mathbb{N}$ with

- simplices: tuples $(k_1,\ldots, k_r)$ with each $k_i\in \mathbb{N}$
- degeneracies:  inserting $0$
- faces: adding consecutive entries or deleting end entries

I'm interested superadditive sequences of natural numbers (in connection with Lusternik-Schnirelmann category of spaces), and I've been led to a construction that takes a superadditive sequence and produces a sub-simplicial set   $C \subseteq N\mathbb{N}$ that has the following TWO additional properties:

- $C$ is closed under permutation of tuples
- if $( \bar k_1,\bar\ell) \in C$ and $\sum \bar k_1 = \sum \bar k_2$ then $(\bar k_2,\ell)\in C$ as well.

So my questions:

- have such sub-simplicial sets been studied somewhere?
- are there `obvious' things that are true about them?
- what are their geometric realizations like?

EDIT: Additional constraint on $C$ (substitution rule).

Comment: Your simplicial set is actually a $\Gamma$-set (in the sense of Segal): the $\Gamma$-structure in particular encodes the symmetric group actions.  So perhaps you are really interested in sub-$\Gamma$-sets?  (Not that I have anything to say about those either.)

Comment: I'll look into it!